# Spotfire to Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, business-intelligence, spotfire, spotfire-analyst

I am converting a Spotfire report to Power BI and am stuck with one of the calculated column. I have the below calculation in Spotfire:

```
when 
([Target Date]>=DateAdd("day",-DayOfWeek(DateTimeNow()),DateTimeNow())) and 
([Target Date]<=DateAdd("Week",8,DateTimeNow())) 
then First([Start of Week]) OVER ([WeekNum],[Year])
else NULL
END
```

Here I do not understand how to write the then clause
`First([Start of Week]) OVER ([WeekNum],[Year])`
in Power Query or DAX

Would appreciate any help or guidance.

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippet you afforded `First([Start of Week]) OVER ([WeekNum],[Year])`, you are trying to get the **Week Start Date** for a specific `[Target Date]` :
Using DAX :

```
YourCalculatedColumn =
    Switch ( True(),
        (
        ([Target Date]>= DateAdd(DateTimeNow(),-DayOfWeek(DateTimeNow()),day) ) 
         && 
        ([Target Date]<= DateAdd(DateTimeNow()),8,day)) ,
        
        [Target Date] – WEEKDAY([Target Date],2) + 1,
        NULL
        )
```